# I can't find the right determinant using elementary row operation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not able to find the determinant using elementary row operation, the answer is $28$,  am I doing anything wrong?

[image: https://imgur.com/rXiAhzB.jpg]

Comment: Except your second operation all are incorrect. The row with which you are performing linear transformation must have coefficient 1 only. If you desire to perform any Linear transformation , then you must divide the determinant by the coefficient you multiply to the row you are performing the operation

Comment: It seems right.

Comment: Under the first identity, shouldn’t it be 4 instead of -3 in the second row?

Comment: Learn the pivotal condensation formula-(i) ii is easy to use (ii) it does row-reduction automaically and (iii) it is computionally very efficient